# Color Mismatch In JavaFX8 Labels

Tags: java, css, image, user-interface, javafx

I was using an image editor last night for a certain picture. I set the text in the picture to #00fffb(cyan), later that day I made a program in JavaFX8 and noticed that a label set to the same color(#00fffb) did not have the same color on screen. I also noticed that the cyan-looking colors looked different in the color chooser than they do on screen. NOTE: The fonts were the same as well. Also, I used a black background to compare the two. [image]
[image]

Label CSS:

```
.controlScreenLabel{
-fx-font-family: Lucida Fax;
-fx-font-size: 23px;
-fx-text-fill: #00fffb;
}
```

Comment: Anti aliasing perhaps?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Doubtful, that only improves the look, generally not the color.

Comment: But the fall off from the solid to the clear could distort the coloring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [subpixel rendering](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/lcd_text_support_in_javafx).

Zoom in on the [Updates] label and you will see typical rainbow colors produced by that tech.

There is probably a switch to turn it off (though I don't know how it globally).

I think you can use [css](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) to manipulate the rendering from stylesheets: see `-fx-font-smoothing-type: gray`.  Of you can set values in [code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html#fontSmoothingTypeProperty).

You can read up on [subpixel rendering on Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).

**Error in your CSS**

Your label css is not setting the font correctly, it should quote the font family, for example:

```
-fx-font-family: 'Lucida Fax';
```

Comment: I don't know how to do disable it. Should I post it in a new question?